# How can I check if the user has a role for one to one relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have an application with User and Role model and a one to one relationship between them. How can I check if the user has a role. I am getting an `SQLSTATE[42S22]` error.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `roles` where `roles`.`user_id` = 1 and `roles`.`user_id` is not null and `name` = client limit 1)

- Database Structure

```
Users
---------------
* id
* name
* email
* password
* role_id
* created_at

Roles
---------------
 * id
 * name
 * slug
 * created_at
```

- App/Models/User

```
public function role() 
{
    return $this->hasOne(Role::class);
}

public function hasRole(string $role) 
{
    if ($this->role()->where('name', $role)->first()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

- App/Models/Role

```
public function users() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Comment: That error is informing you that you have not defined a `user_id` column in your `roles` table which will store the `id` of the `user`. You need to define that first.

Comment: Is that correct? A user has 1 role, and a role has 1 user? If it's right, do you need a table named roles? Or a role can have many users? In this case role_id should be in user table.

Comment: @Unflux Actually I have a role_id on the users table which is a foreign id. But then again I am unable to call the `role()` relation inside the `hasRole` public function.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I already have the column present in the users table, its just I am unable to call the `role()` relation which is defined in the model, inside the public function `hasRole`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invert the relation. User has 1 role, Role has many Users

Role:

```
public function users() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

User:

```
public function role() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

It's a One To Many relation. See the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Okay, I got that, but why can't I call the `role()` relation inside the `hasRole` function? Its searching for the `user_id` column in `roles` table but its `role_id` column in `users` table.

Comment: You can, after you fix the relation between your models. Eloquent will evaluate the relationship and build the query. That's why it's trying to use `user_id` column in `role` table, because your relation is inverted.

Comment: Okay now I understand, thanks alot mate, its working now :)

Comment: I am successfully able to check if the user who is logging in has a single role, but what can I do incase I need to check for an array of roles and if any of them satisfy the condition return true else false. this is what I am doing to check for multiple roles, `$this->role()->whereIn('name', $roles)->first()`, but I guess I am unable to check an array of roles.

Comment: Better to open a new question in SO with all relevant code.

Comment: Yes, I have asked one, please have a look if you can spare some time. Thanks alot!
https://stackoverflow.com/q/65945365/13399106

Comment: How can I associate a role to a user in such relationship as I am unable to do so. Please help me, https://stackoverflow.com/q/65948353/13399106