# How to check for a role from an array of roles and return true if any of the role exists, for one to many relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am successfully able to check if the user has a single role. Now what I need here to check is, if the user is either an administrator or an employee, and if any of the above role matches then return true else false. I am unable to do so as I am using one to many relationship between `users` and `roles` so I am unable to check the role from an array of roles.

- Database Structure

```
Users
---------------
* id
* name
* email
* password
* role_id
* created_at

Roles
---------------
 * id
 * name
 * slug
 * created_at
```

- App/Models/User

```
public function role() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}

public function hasRole(string $role) 
{
    if ($this->role()->where('slug', $role)->exists()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function hasAnyRoles(array $roles) 
{
    if ($this->role()->whereIn('slug', $roles)->exists()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

- App/Models/Role

```
public function users() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

- App/Http/Responses/LoginResponse

```
public function toResponse($request)
{
    if(Auth::user()->hasAnyRoles(['administrator', 'employee'])) {
        return redirect()->route('backend.dashboard');
    }

    return redirect()->route('frontend.dashboard');
}
```

Comment: you can just load that relationship since it is only a single record then you can check against that role slug

Comment: On a side note (in case this is not just a toy/experiment) there is a library [laravel-permission](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v4/introduction) provided by Spatie that does exactly what you are working on.

Comment: @lagbox Please check the `LoginResponse`, I am trying to check if a user has either an administrator role or an employee role, if any of the above role exists, redirect to backend else frontend.

Comment: yea i know what you are doing, you can load that relationship and use `in_array` to see if the slug is in the array of roles

Comment: @lagbox Can you show me the code, if incase you can spare some time. As I am blank on how to take this forward. Thanks already!

Comment: The query you have made should work

Answer (score 0):

You could use `in_array` to see if the slug of the role assigned is in the array you are passing:

```
public function hasAnyRoles(array $roles) 
{
    if ($this->role) {
        return in_array($this->role->slug, $roles);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but its still the same, idk what's the problem here. :/

Comment: then this user doesn't have that role or the slugs are wrong

Comment: The roles are assigned, its only happening when I give an array of roles to check from, when its a single string, its working flawless, but in case of an array, event after role being defined, this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a one-to-many inverse relationship you cannot do whereIn. Instead you can use this.

```
public function role() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}

public function hasRole(string $role) 
{
    return $this->role()->where('slug', $role)->exists();
}

public function hasAnyRoles(array $roles) 
{
    if (is_array($roles)) {
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            if ($this->hasRole($role)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried but its still the same. When I am logging as an admin its redirecting to the backend but when as an employee, its still the same.

Comment: As @lagbox said in his answer then the user does not have that role or is passing an empty array. The error is in the data, not in the logic.