# Getting an error when associating role to a user for one to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a one to many relationship between `users` and `roles`. I am unable to associate a role to a user while saving or updating a user, as its throwing me an error while saving the model. Please spare some time to have a look below.

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[3]' for column `management`.`users`.`role_id` at row 1 (SQL: update `users` set `role_id` = [3], `users`.`updated_at` = 2021-01-29 04:44:19 where `id` = 3)

- Database Structure

```
Users
----------
* id
* name
* email
* password
* role_id
* created_at

Roles
----------
* id
* name
* slug
* created_at
```

- User Model

```
public function role() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

- Role Model

```
public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

- User Controller

```
public $showUserUpdationModal = false;
public $role;
public User $user;

protected $rules = [
    'user.name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'user.email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
    'role' => 'required',
];

public function storeUser()
{
    $this->validate();
    $this->validate([
        'user.email' => 'unique:users,email,'.$this->user->id,
    ]);
    $this->user->role()->associate($this->role);
    $this->user->save();
    $this->showUserUpdationModal = false;

    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('notify', $this->user->name.' Updated Successfully');
    $this->emit('sectionRefresh');
}
```

Comment: Where are you assigning `$this->roles` and can you `dd()` it.

Comment: Yes, I was picking the ids as an array in the public function `updateUser` which displays the value from the database. That was causing the error, as it expects an integer. I have resolved the issue now.